# Is there any way for me to trace the TeamViewer ID of a machine that hacked in?

Tags: attacks, forensics, incident-response

I am wondering if there is any list I could access to find TeamViewer ID's, as the police are not being helpful about this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you could try to find the teamviewerID via either teamviewer's logs or the registry of the victim's PC.

The local teamviewer log file will be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\TeamViewer8_Logfile.log` or similar (as described [here](http://forensicartifacts.com/2012/12/teamviewer-8/)).

Also look in `..\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer\Connections.txt` for potentially more information on who connected to you.

Lastly, there is a wealth of information in the registry itself, as described in the link given.

There are plenty of articles out there on where to look exactly. search for `teamviewer forensic artifacts`.

I'd say that if you look in these files and can present some basic proof (unknown Id 'x' accessed my pc at 'y' time) to the law enforcement, they may look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have been able to get the teamviewer id of the attacker ([like in this Thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35229/24382))? 
If so i would recommend you read [this Technet-Entry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700813.aspx) (even it is Microsoft).

But regarding your Question: Stick with the officials. Srsly.

Comment: Could you perhaps add a brief description of each page, to prevent this answer from becoming useless if the links change? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there is much of an answer here. There is general advice on having been hacked, and that's it. The OP is not addressed.